# Storing a three-dimensional object in a one-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a cube, and the cube's dimensions are 16 * 16 * 16, where each dimension starts at index 0, and ends at index 15. Every unit of that cube has to be stored separately; no two units can collide. If I'm trying to store the data in an array such as:

```
Unit[] units = new Unit[4096];
```

How would I go about correctly indexing objects? I can't seem to come up with a formula to do it correctly.

Comment: Just use modular math and think base 16. 16 * 16 * z + 16 * y + x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use modular math and think base 16

```
16 * 16 * z + 16 * y + x.
```

Comment: just to note: instead of 16* you can use left shifts, usually they are a little bit faster

Comment: @IlyaBursov: all well and good, but what if the base changes to 15? or 20?

Comment: then you should either return to multiplication or try some hack, like 20*x = 16*x + 4*x = (x<<4)+(x<<2) and so on

Comment: This is roughly what I was looking for, I just forgot that z and y have to be within the bounds of 0 to 15, and x can be within 0 and 16. Thanks!

Comment: @PuppyKevin: no -- ***ALL*** variables must be between 0 and 15. `x` is no exception. How could it possibly be otherwise? Or one side of your cube would be eccentric and it would no longer be a cube.

Comment: ...0 - 4095, not 4096. You're right, my mistake. Thank you once again!